# Custom cells repeating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I have an app that has a tableview embedded in a ViewController and whenever I navigate to another ViewController and navigate back to the table view, the cells repeat when I scroll. Does anyone have any advice on how to prevent this? The current code for the tableview is :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return marathonRaces.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let singleCell: marathonTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("marathonCell") as! marathonTableViewCell

    singleCell.marathonName.text = marathonRaces[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.entry.text = "\(entryNumber[indexPath.row])"
    singleCell.entries.text = "\(entires[indexPath.row])"
    singleCell.length.text = "\(length[indexPath.row])"

    return singleCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = self.marathonsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let currentCell = marathonsTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! marathonTableViewCell

    let marathonEvents = currentCell.marathonName.text

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("marathonDetail", sender: self)
}
```

I am using swift, xcode7, and parse as my backend

the only relevant code within viewDidAppear would be :

```
var query = PFQuery(className: “Marathons")
    query.orderByAscending("end")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (marathons, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil ){
        //success

            for marathon in marathons! {
            self.marathonRaces
          .append(marathon[“marathonName"] as! String)
            self.entry.append(marathon[“entryNumber"] as! Int)
            self.entries.append(marathon[“entries"] as! Int)
            self.length.append(marathon[“length"] as! Int)



            }

            self.marathonsTableView.reloadData()

        }else {
        print(error)

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "repeat" mean in "the table view the cells repeat when I scroll"?

Comment: does the `marathonRaces` array has duplicate elements by any chance?

Comment: if your array have 3 items, you will cell 3 cells with 4 labels each!!!! and 3 of the labels will have same text on all the cells!!!! IS this what you called repeat ?

Comment: I apologize so upon seeing the view controller there is currently cells:
race 1
race 2
race 3
race 4
but once I navigate to another view controller and then back to the view controller with the table the cells are 
race 1
race 2
race 3
race 4
race 1
race 2
race 3
race 4
and they multiply more everytime I navigate back and forth

Comment: can you share your `viewDidAppear`/`viewWillAppear` methods?

Comment: I added them to my original post since it was too long for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `viewDidAppear` method. Every time the controller appears you fetch data from background, append them to your arrays and reload the tableview. Move the code for fetching data to `viewDidLoad` for example and "repeating" should be gone.

Comment: Thank you I spent hours googling and try other things

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the datasource `marathonRaces` is gaining more entries?

You may be adding more entries on each back navigation, if so either do not add them or remove all entries prior to adding them.

Comment: How would I check if more entries are being added, I do not believe they are being added as marathonRaces is an array in which data is being appended to by a Parse Query

Comment: var marathonRaces = [String]()

var entry = [Int]()

var entries = [Int]()
    var length = [Int]()